# No filesystem could mount root

Tags: 12.10, kernel, filesystem, root, syslinux

I am trying to boot a linux kernel 3.7.0 on virtualbox and it keeps telling me the same message: "No filesystem could mount root tried ext3 ext4 vfat fusebk". I put append root=/dev/sda in my isolinux cfg file even though there is no file named /dev/sda.